# Sum of Random Variables

Tags: self-study, random-variable, density-function

As part of my statistical mechanics class, I'm trying to go through Kardar's statistical physics of particles and I'm having trouble with this one line:

> Consider the sum $X=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^N x_i$, where $x_i$ are random variables with a joint PDF of $p(\mathbf{x})$.  The PDF of $X$ is:
>
> $p_X(x) = \displaystyle\int d^N\mathbf{x}p(\mathbf{x}) \delta(x-\sum x_i) = \int \prod_{i=1}^{N-1} dx_ip(x_1,\ldots,x_{N-1},x-x_1 - \cdots-x_{N-1})$

My two questions are: why is that first integral the pdf for $X$ and how does that second equality follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that $\delta(\cdot)$ denotes the Dirac delta or impulse which has
the *sifting property*
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x-a)\,\mathrm dx = 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(a-x)\,\mathrm dx = f(a)$$
provided that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x=a$. If so, the integral
is merely over all points in $\mathbb R^n$ for which the sum $\sum_i x_i$
equals $x$.  The following simple example illustrates (I hope!) what is
going on.

For *two* random variables $X$ and $Y$, the density of their sum $Z$ is given
by
$$\begin{align}
f_Z(z) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x, z-x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left[
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\delta((z-x)-y)\,\mathrm dy
\right]\,\mathrm dx\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y)\delta(z-x-y)\,\mathrm dy
\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}$$