# Probability Density Function of a linear combination of 2 dependent random variables, when joint density is known

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, density-function, joint-distribution

Let's say there are two dependent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with joint density function $f$.

What is the PDF of the weighted sum of these two variables, $Z = aX + bY$?

Thanks in advance for any advice or references!

Comment: This is *nearly* a duplicate of [How to add two dependent random variables?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/21549/22228), except that you include coefficients $a$ and $b$. I think it might be better to say you are interested in a *linear combination*  rather than just a "sum", since that is dealt with elsewhere on this site.

Comment: (There's a [related post here about the sum of discrete random variables](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/115198/22228).)

Comment: Let $A = aX$ and $B = bY$. Then, the joint density $f_{A,B}(\alpha, \beta)$ is given by $$f_{A,B}(\alpha, \beta) = \frac{1}{|ab|}f_{X,Y}\left(\frac{\alpha}{a},\frac{\beta}{b}\right).$$ Now apply the method described in the question pointed out by Silverfish.